# Pandas advanced read_excel or ExcelFile.parse

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-excel

I'm trying to do some conditional parsing of excel files into Pandas dataframes.  I have a group of excel files and each has some number of lines at the top of the file that are not part of the data -- some identification data based on what report parameters were used to create the report.

I want to use the `ExcelFile.parse()` method with `skiprows=some_number` but I don't know what some_number will be for each file.

I do know that the `HeaderRow` will start with one member of a list of possibilities.  How can I tell `Pandas` to create the `dataframe` starting on the row that includes any some_string in my list of possibilities?

Or, is there a way to import the entire sheet and then remove the rows preceding the row that includes any some_string in my list of possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time I would just post-process this in pandas, i.e. diagnose, remove the rows, and correct the dtypes, in pandas. This has the benefit of being easier *but* is arguably less elegant (I suspect it'll also be *faster* doing it this way!):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['blah', 1, 2], ['some_string', 3, 4], ['foo', 5, 6]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
             0  1  2
0         blah  1  2
1  some_string  3  4
2          foo  5  6

In [13]: df[0].isin(['some_string']).argmax()  # assuming it's found
Out[13]: 1
```

I may actually write this in python, as it's probably little/no benefit in vectorizing (and I find this more readable):

```
def to_skip(df, preceding):
    for s in enumerate(df[0]):
        if s in preceding:
            return i
    raise ValueError("No preceding string found in first column")

In [21]: preceding = ['some_string']

In [22]: to_skip(df, preceding)
Out[22]: 1

In [23]: df.iloc[1:]  # or whatever you need to do
Out[23]:
             0  1  2
1  some_string  3  4
2          foo  5  6
```

---

The other possibility, messing about with ExcelFile and finding the row number could be doing (again with a for-loop as above but in openpyxl or similar). However, I don't *think* there would be a way to read the excel file (xml) just once if you do this.

This is somewhat unfortunate when compared to how you could do this on a csv, where you can read the first few lines (until you see the row/entry you want), and then pass this **opened** file to `read_csv`. (If you can export your Excel spreadsheet to csv then parse in pandas, that would be faster/cleaner...)

*Note: `read_excel` isn't really that fast anyways (esp. compared to `read_csv`)... so IMO you want to get to pandas asap.*

Comment: Thanks Andy Hayden. I suspected that loading the entire file and using Pandas to clean up was the way to go. For the read_csv, that would be nice, but the current expected input is a zipfile of xls and xlsx docs, and converting them before reading seems really inefficient. Do you know if read_excel is any faster then the ExcelFile.parse() method?

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts one calls the other, there's no difference in performance :)